# Sony camera turn-off with API

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I am using Sony WX-220 on airplan drone for mapping purposes. i am connecting plane onboard computer to camera via Wi-Fi,  on landing i want to turn off camera , how can i do that. I tried autopoweroff but it didnt work-"unsopported command"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the autopoweroff flag will not turn the camera off instantly. It will just set the time the camera will turn off on it's own when it is not being used. If you use this flag it is also a good idea to run the getSupportedAutoPowerOff flag to see what autopoweroff times the camera supports. For instance, it may only support 60 seconds.

This is the only flag that controls the power.